# queue operation on the same coroutine

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

I'm receiving data through bluetooth with a custom protocol so I need to "decode" the packet and then show the result. I'm using a function of an object (singleton) to decode the bytes received but the communication is async so it's possible that I'm decoding the bytes/packet while I'm receiving other bytes. I need a solution to process the incoming data sequentially and not call the decode function while I'm already decoding a previous packet.

Here is my actual code. I tried to use mutex without success. Using a defined coroutineScope I should work on the same coroutine. Obviously the decode process have to run in background.

// Activity

```
bluetoothService.incomingData.observe(this, {
   viewModel.getData(it) })
```

// ViewModel

```
private var coroutineJob = Job()
private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + coroutineJob)


fun getData(bytes: ByteArray) { 
    getDataSafeCall(bytes)
}

private fun getDataSafeCall(bytes: ByteArray) {
   
    uiScopeJob = uiScope.launch {
        Packet.processMessage(bytes.toUByteArray()).collect {
            updateData(it)
        }
    }
}
```

// Packet Object

```
object Packet {
    
        private val mutex = Mutex()
    
        suspend fun processMessage(buffer: UByteArray) = flow {
            
            mutex.withLock {
                decode(buffer).collect { emit(it) }
            }
        }
    
        
        private fun decode(buffer: UByteArray) = channelFlow {
          // Here I'm processing my packet and then
          offer()
        }
}
```

EDIT: This is part of the Bluetooth Service if it helps to understand more, even if there's no problem receiving data.

// BluetoothService

```
class BluetoothService : Service() {

    private val btChannel: BtChannel by inject()

    private var socket: BluetoothSocket? = null
    
    private val receivedLive = MutableLiveData<ByteArray>()

    fun incomingData(): LiveData<ByteArray> {
        if (socket != null) {
           socket.let {
                btChannel.read(socket).onEach 
               {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        receivedLive.value = it
                    }
                }.launchIn(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO))
           }
        }
        return receivedLive
    }
}
```

Comment: Typical solution is to use a single thread/coroutine to receive/send data. Start a coroutine that reads the data in a loop and it passes it to e.g. some `Channel`. Similarly when sending - single coroutine that reads from `Channel` and sends through IO.

Comment: It sounds like the problem comes from the shared buffer rather than concurrent decoding. If the caller of `getData` reuses the `bytes` buffer that is passed as argument, you need to be sure it has been entirely processed before you even return from `getData` (or you need another way to tell the caller it can reclaim the buffer), so IMO the problem happens earlier than in `decode`. Even with a single `decode` call at a time, you could be decoding the buffer while someone is writing to it, which is already a problem.

Comment: Given my above comment, could you please elaborate on how `getData` is called?

Comment: @broot In my case is not a request/response system, I could and I usually receive data without requesting it so I'm not sure about your solution but could you explain more?

Comment: @Joffrey I don't think is a problem about shared buffer because I put a "log" before the `mutex.withLock {}` and I always receive all the data. The problem starts when I receive "a lot" of bytes, for example more than 3 Kb. An empty packet (without payload) is 7 bytes long. In my opinion when I receive 3 Kb the switching between main thread and suspended function is slower. Anyway the getData function is called like I wrote in the question, I observe the LiveData "bluetoothService.incomingData" and every time I receive new bytes I call getData.

Comment: @Pico thanks for the additional info. It may seem like the buffer is not reused, but that depends on the implementation of `btChannel.read(socket)`, which I can't see here. I have another question as well, do you really decode multiple elements from a single bytearray? You seem to be mixing flow and suspend functions in a strange way, and I wonder whether you even need flows at all here. Also why use a `channelFlow`? Do you spawn multiple coroutines to decode the array?